# Most efficient implementation of ID Tracking system

Tags: java

I am currently working on a simple ID tracking system for a "game" I'm working on. I am expecting to have a few hundred objects on screen at any given time.

Many of these objects need to interact with other specific objects, however these objects are very quickly created and destroyed.

I want to implement and ID system to keep track of which ID's are used.

Due to the nature of the program I want to be able to reuse an ID after the object is destroyed and marked as available.

This is my thought process on how to do this efficiently:

- I don't want to have to loop through all current ID's to check if one is available
- A simple yes or no answer as to whether that ID is taken is good enough
- This could be done with a boolean array, but an array is limited to it's initial size
- This could be done with a list but I would either need to have a new object for each number on the list or I would need to loop through the list.
- The best option would be an array like object that is marked false for every position and only marked true once that number has been taken then returned to false when it's done

Something like this:

```
IDTracker tracker = new IDTracker();

public boolean checkID(int numToCheck) {
    return tracker.get(numToCheck);
}

//returns true if successful
public boolean takeID(int numToTake) {
    if(!checkID(numToCheck)) {
        tracker.set(3) = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//returns true if successful
public void releaseID(int numToRelease) {
    if(checkID(numToCheck)) {
        tracker.set(3) = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know how to do this with a List, but that would require having a boolean object for 10k+ ID's. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Seems valid to me, I wrote an answer

Comment: @bhspencer Fair enough, but OP said he knew how to do with a List.  A Set is better but he could have replicated your code using a List - so what is he really asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a Set.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

```
Set<Integer> tracker = new HashSet<>();

public boolean checkID(int numToCheck) {
    return tracker.contains(numToCheck);
}

public boolean takeID(int numToTake) {
    if(!checkID(numToTake)) {
        tracker.add(numToTake);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void releaseID(int numToRelease) {
    if(checkID(numToRelease)) {
        tracker.remove(numToRelease);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something available I just couldn't remember what. Will accept in 2 minutes.